# Increase and Decay Question why is $500(1.05)^5$ not equal to $500(0.95)^5$?

Tags: exponential-function

I would think the values would be the same but the increase is $638.1$ an $138$ dollar increase and the decrease is $386.89$ an $113.10$ decrease.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Your title is clearly wrong.  As $1.05\gt 0.95$ you should expect that $1.05^5 \gt 0.95^5$

Comment: Let's replace $5$ with $1$ to begin. Would you expect $1.05^1$ equal $0.95^1$? And if they are not equal, why should $500\cdot 1.05^1$ equal $500\cdot 0.95^1$...?

Answer (score 2):

It is a general phenomenon.  If you increase a number by some percentage then decrease the result by the same percentage, you get a smaller number.  That is because the reduction applies to a larger number than the increase.  If $x$ is the increase, you have $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2 \lt 1$

Comment: This answer seems a bit off-topic — OP decreases the same _base_ $500$, not a result of the previous increase...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Ross.

Comment: @CiaPan:  but after the first reduction, the base is smaller.

Comment: @RossMillikan I disagree. The question, specified in the title actually, is: _'why is $500(1.05)^5$ not equal to $500(0.95)^5$?'_ With clearly the same base of $500$, increased $5$ times by $5\%$ in the first case and decreased 5 times by $5\%$ in the second case. You just have **guessed** what OP meant (and you apparently did it right!), but still you answer your guess, not the question actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

An **increase** is when something gets bigger. A **decrease** is when something gets smaller. The different names indicate those are different effects, hence they give different results. Why would you expect the results equal?

As a result of an increase of an initial value of $500$ you get more than $500$. On the other hand, a decrease of the same initial value of $500$ results in less than $500$.

Possibly you meant applying some percentage-defined increase to a given initial value $500$ and then applying a decrease *to a result of the previous growth*, not to the same initial $500$...?
If so, you have two steps:

1. Initial_Value = $500$ increases, say, by $10\%$, which is $500\cdot\frac{10}{100} = 50$.
   As a result you get Increased_Value = $500 + 50 = 550$.
2. Then the Increased_Value = $550$ decreases by apparently "the same" $10\%$. But this time the percentage applies to the Increased_Value, which is $550$, so a decrease is $550\cdot \frac{10}{100}=55$.
   As a result we get the Final_Value = $550 - 55 = 495 < 500$.

The crucial part is that we apply "the same" percentage to **different values**: when increasing, we multiply the initial, not-yet grown value by $0.1$, but to decrease we multiply the grown value by $0.1$. As a result the actual increase is smaller than the actual decrease ($50$ vs. $55$) hence the net result of $+p\%$ followed by $-p\%$ is negative, as Ross Millikan shows in more general way in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2510873).